# How to prevent automatic line-breaks before Japanese punctuation using TCPDF?

Tags: php, regex, unicode, tcpdf

I'm using PHP to generate Japanese PDF documents using [TCPDF](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/) because it has great support for Unicode.

However, the regular expression used to wrap long blocks of text in languages where "words" are not separated by spaces inserts line breaks at inappropriate positions, most notably just before [punctuation characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_punctuation). For example, the breaks should happen after `。` (ideographic full stop, Unicode 3002) or `、` (comma, Unicode 3001), not just before.

I tried limiting the regex to match any separator BUT punctuation characters using `/(?!\xa0)[\s\p{Z}](?!\p{P})/u` but it doesn't work (and I don't know why).

Here is my testcase code (you'll need to download TCPDF and unzip it into the same folder).

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
$pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);
$pdf->setFont('cid0jp', '', 12);
$pdf->setSpacesRE('/(?!\xa0)[\s\p{Z}]/u'); // This is what TCPDF suggests: any space or separator, unless preceded by a non-breaking space
$pdf->SetMargins(50, 20);
$pdf->AddPage();
$html = '<style>.wrap {width: 20mm;}</style><div class="wrap">一一般には、疑問文の最後に、終止符に換えて置かれる。このため、疑問符は文の終わりをも示す。ただし、しばしば文の途中の疑問を表したい単語（不明確なことなど）の直後に置かれる。この場合、括弧で囲むことが多い。</div>';
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);
$pdf->EndPage();
$pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'I');
```

I'd be very grateful to anyone who can improve the expression so that no `。` or `、` appears at the start of a new line!

Edit:
I spent some time fine-tuning the regex, here is an updated version:

```
// Select spaces or word boundaries, unless at the very start of the string, immediately preceded by opening parenthesis or braces, or immediately followed by an ideographic full stop, comma or any kind of parenthesis.
$pdf->setSpacesRE('/(?<!^|\x{a0}|\x{ff08}|\x{ff5b}|\x{ff3b}|\x{3010})(\s|\b|\p{Z})(?!\x{3001}|\x{3002}|\x{ff09}|\x{ff5d}|\x{ff3d}|\x{3011})/u');
```

This doesn't work well when the text is interspersed with non-Japanese words, and though it now splits the text more appropriately (as far as I can tell, because I don't speak Japanese) the library still breaks the words in the wrong places when they don't fit. I'll keep tweaking, but I start to believe that the text-splitting algorithm itself needs to behave differently when dealing with Asian languages.

Comment: If it can help, it seems that `[\x{3000}-\x{303F}]` should be used. ref : http://www.localizingjapan.com/blog/2012/01/20/regular-expressions-for-japanese-text/